# Pandas merge on multiple file and saving it on the same file

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have 4 files which I need to merge with another file and save it. Here is what I have tried so far,

```
ref ='/home/user/Dir/Reference'
ref = pd.read_csv(ref, sep='\t', header=0)
#T_seq = T_seq.reset_index(drop=False)
#data_frames = []
for filename in file_DE:
    name   = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename))
    files  = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', header=0)
for eachfile in files:
    files_merged  = pd.merge(eachfile, ref , left_on='Gene' , right_on= 'Gene')
```

But when I print the files_merged, it has only headers,

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene, baseMean , log2FoldChange , lfcSE , stat , pvalue , padj, Gene_sym, Gene_type]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene, baseMean , log2FoldChange , lfcSE , stat , pvalue , padj, Gene_sym, Gene_type]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene, baseMean , log2FoldChange , lfcSE , stat , pvalue , padj, Gene_sym, Gene_type]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Gene, baseMean , log2FoldChange , lfcSE , stat , pvalue , padj, Gene_sym, Gene_type]
Index: []
In [67]:
```

I mean an empty data frame, The Index 'Gene' from file ref and and all others 'files' have matcching rows, but in this way its only returning back an empty dataframe.

In the end, what I am aiming is a data frame with all rows filled with values, not the just header and empty data frame​ as I have now.

Any help is really appreciated

Thank you

​

Comment: use `sep='\s+'` instead

Comment: Thanks it helped. Also could you, please walk me how can save it separate as four files.Now all the merged files are saved together in files_merged.

Comment: do you want to save merged DF into single CSV file or to multiple ones?

Comment: yes, Multiple ones..Now it's being saved in single file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it this way:

```
sep = r'\s+'
ref ='/home/user/Dir/Reference'
ref = pd.read_csv(ref, sep=sep, header=0)

for filename in file_DE:
    name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(filename))
    df   = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=sep, header=0)
    pd.merge(df, ref, on='Gene').to_csv('merged_' + name, index=False)
```

Comment: It complains as,TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: which line produces this error? can you also provide a sample data sets, so we could test our solutions?

Comment: Sorry now its working..Yeah but the files are not saved anywhere

Comment: they are saved in the "current" directory. you can add path to the file names

Comment: Sorry I checked wrong directory and its there ..:) Thank you so much

Comment: @user1017373, glad to help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108541/discussion-between-user1017373-and-maxu).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the intersection of your `Gene` columns is not empty?

Because this works:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, merge

from numpy.random import randint, seed

seed(4321)

shape = (10,2)

ref = DataFrame(
    data=randint(1, 4, shape),
    columns=['a','b']
)

csvs = [DataFrame(randint(1, 13, shape), columns=['a','c']) for _ in range(4)]

for csv in csvs:
    print merge(
        csv, ref,
        left_on='a',
        right_on='a'
    ).head()
```

With output:

```
   a  c  b
0  2  7  3
1  2  7  2
2  2  7  3
3  2  7  1
4  2  7  1
   a  c  b
0  2  9  3
1  2  9  2
2  2  9  3
3  2  9  1
4  2  9  1
   a  c  b
0  2  9  3
1  2  9  2
2  2  9  3
3  2  9  1
4  2  9  1
   a  c  b
0  2  9  3
1  2  9  2
2  2  9  3
3  2  9  1
4  2  9  1
```

Comment: Yes,it's not empty. Actually, the above script which I have in my question works ..I need to save it in multiple files.